# Clear UITableView Cache

Tags: ios, uikit

My UITableView data source gets updated in background thread based on user action. And I am reDisplaying cells in foreground. Problem is if number of rows in new data is less than the number of rows in previous data, I can still see old rows listed after the new rows.

After 15-20 seconds these old rows are automatically deleted (sometimes it is faster). Or if I go to different screen and comeback to my tableview (with the datasource unchanged), the old rows are no more there. My guess is there is some cache that needs force deletion. Any ideas how to do it?

Here is snapshot of my code

```
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    LoadingCompleted = NO;
    if ([lbl.text isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        [self getData:month Year:year];
        LoadingCompleted = YES;
    }
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (LoadingCompleted) {
            mainDataSource = mainDataSourceCopy;
            [self.tableView  reloadData];
        }
    );
```

});

Weird output that I am getting in my tableview:
New Row 1
New Row 2
Old Row 3
Old Row 4
Old Row 5

Answer (score 4):

You must not change the data source array in a background thread, because it may be
accessed from the main UI thread during the modifications.

You should update
a separate array in the background thread instead, and then assign it to the data
source array on the main thread:

```
// ... compute newArray ...

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // Update data source array and reload table view.
    self.dataSourceArray = newArray;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
});
```

Comment: @user1041086: The problem is probably in your getData method. Does mainDataSourceCopy have the correct contents?

Comment: Yup the contents are correct. I think - the old rows are getting cleared when the next drawing cycle kicks. Because it is happening automatically without me touching anything.

Comment: @user1041086: There is no "table view cache". Table view *cells* are "cached" for reuse but that has probably nothing to do with your problem. - When you call reloadData, the table view calls your numberOfRowsInSection method first to get the new number of items. Then cellForRowAtIndexPath is called for each *visible* cell to display the contents. - So you might check that these methods work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`-reloadData`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadData) on the table view.

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

EDIT:
I noticed that you said you were updating on a background thread, so just in case use [`performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelectorOnMainThread%3awithObject%3awaitUntilDone%3a):

```
[tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Or you can use GCD's [`dispatch_async()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008079-CH2-SW7)

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // Set new data
    [tableView reloadData];
});
```

Comment: I am using dispatch_async. Not working :(. Pls check my code above. Thanks.