# Index Out of range Swift

Tags: swift, tableview

I occasionally get an error 'Index out of Range' from the following code:

I suspect its to do with the way the table data is reloaded and have tried moving it in and out of the loop but no avail.

any help resolving this would be much appreciated!

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {


        self.tableView.rowHeight = 150

        self.tableData.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)
        self.tableImages.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)
        self.tableDesc.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)

        // Register custom cell
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "vwTblCell", bundle: nil)
        tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")


            let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.checkmyweave.co.uk/backend/offerstest.php")!

            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url as URL) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

                if let urlContent = data {

                    do {

                        if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: []) as? [[String:AnyObject]] {


                            var i = 0

                            while i < jsonResult.count {


                                self.tableData.append(jsonResult[i]["offertitle"]! as! String)
                                self.tableImages.append(jsonResult[i]["imagename"]! as! String)
                                self.tableDesc.append(jsonResult[i]["offerdesc"]! as! String)


                                i = i + 1

                            }

                        }

                    } catch {

                        print("JSON serialization failed")

                    }

                } else {

                    print("ERROR FOUND HERE")
                }

                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in

                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                })
            }

            task.resume()



    }
```

Comment: Even if the language is different, it is essentially the same problem as the one described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23041387/1187415: You must not modify the data source on a background thread.

Comment: where does this error occur exactly ?

Comment: You can change your data model in background, but you have to make sure that reloadData() is called from main queue only. Also, you should use weak references to `self` in blocks to avoid unnecessary retain. Have you checked `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method? Maybe you returning more than you have in data model? That can be the reason of crash

Comment: I'm really sorry i'm not sure i follow, the rows in section returns the tableData.count. I can seem to resolve this issue :(